# sending multiple data rows to firebase on clicking one button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Guys <3 
This is my first project with firebase and I wanna send a quite bunch of data to the database, the problem is when I click the button only the last line of code get send, I also tried to but every row in a function and call them one by one, and the same happens, only the last function work and send it's data, here's the button on click code

```
    @IBAction func Send(_ sender: Any) {
    apperfun();
    dnamefun();
    docfun();
    servfun();
    pnamefun();
    pnumfun();
}
```

and here's the functions

```
func apperfun() {
    if ap == "1" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["apperance": "Excellent"])}
    else if ap == "2" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["apperance": "Good"])}
    else if ap == "3" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["apperance": "Bad"])}
}

func dnamefun() {
    self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["dname":dname])
}

func docfun() {
    if doc == "1" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["level": "Excellent"])}
    else if doc == "2" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["level": "Good"])}
    else if doc == "3" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["level": "Bad"])
        self.ref.child("bad").child(pname+phone).setValue(["level": "Bad"])}
}

func servfun() {
    if serv == "1" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["performance": "Excellent"])}
    else if serv == "2" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["performance": "Good"])}
    else if serv == "3" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["performance": "Bad"])}
}

func pnamefun() {
    self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["pname":pname]);
}

func pnumfun() {
    self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["pnum":phone]);
}
    func receptionfun() {
        if recep == "1" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["reception": "Excellent"])}
        else if recep == "2" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["reception": "Good"])}
        else if recep == "3" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["reception": "Bad"])}
    }
```

Comment: To clarify, are you saying only `pnumfun()` ever gets called, or that no matter which function is last, only that last function gets called? Did you put breakpoints in each function to verify they aren't being called?

Comment: Please format the question in a proper way. What do you mean by *only the last line of code get send* , which line? Also update your question with your JSON Database structure, and security rules. Also try printing the values that you are using in  the `if else` scenarios, if they match what you want. I wouldn't be surprised if the case values that you are checking are `Int` like `3` not String `"3"`.

Comment: @JenPerson no matter which function is last, only that last function gets called.. and when I set breakpoints the last function before the breakpoint is the only one that gets called!

Comment: Thanks Jen and @Dravidian .. J. Doe's solution worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setValue will replace any data in that node to your data you are setting. You want to use an update. An update will replace the key if it exists, or add it to your database if it not exists.

You have this:

```
if ap == "1" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).setValue(["apperance": "Excellent"])}
```

It should be:

```
if ap == "1" {self.ref.child("fullinfo").child(pname).updateChildValues(["apperance": "Excellent"])}
```